# How thick in diameter is the average lightning bolt visually?

Tags: lightning

Note that I’m talking about the visual aspect of a lightning bolt: normal lightning bolts, according to a simple Google search, are only about an inch (3 cm) in diameter, but they appear much bigger from a distance thanks to the light they emit. Basically, I’m asking how big a lightning bolt appears to be to the naked eye, not how big a bolt actually is.

Comment: I mean, tbh, I fail to see how this isn’t physics.

Comment: I can personally see lightning even without looking at the bolt directly, so the visual impression of a lightning bolt (as something that illuminates the entire landscape) is fairly wide, for all I can tell. I would say that it pretty much includes the full solid angle.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to put a number on it. The closest lightning bolt I've ever seen (about 30m away,\* Yikes!) seemed to occupy about the same [visual angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_angle) as lightning bolts that I've seen from miles away. But of course, the actual flash is so brief, that mostly what I'm remembering are the [afterimages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterimage) of lightning bolts. I'm _guessing_ that the extreme brightness of a bolt relative to the dark background might make its afterimage look about the same at any distance.

Comment: \* I was indoors, looking out through a window when that one hit in the garden.

Comment: @GodzillaLouise and even if it would not be physics, it would be very interesting how that works. (But I would count any effects inside the body caused  by the light under optics - physics.)

Comment: Consider that the whole sky is blue from the 'flash' of sunlight (which at it's core is hotter than a lightening bolt). Thus what we see is most likely the scatter of light (originating in the plasma) from the air surrounding plasma stream. Then lots of 1/R^2 effects

Comment: Are you expecting that all lightning bolts will appear to the be the same size regardless of other factors, such as the distance between the observer and the bolt, the length of the strike, etc., etc.?

Answer (score 27):

Well, if all what you care is just the visual (subjective) perception of how wide a lightning bolt looks like, here we go. We take as an example lightning which very often hits [CN Tower in Toronto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CN_Tower):

[image]

According to the [public data](http://www.torontoplace.com/attractions/CNtower.htm) tower base is about $66.6~m$ wide.

Now we grab tower schematics -

[image]

and measuring its base in some image editing tool like [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP),- gives us that
tower "inverse DPI" resolution at base is $\approx 85 \text{cm/pixel} \tag 1$.

Now measure in the same image editing program the width of the tower place in pixels where lightning hits,- i.e., the width of the upper part of the antenna, multiply it with $DPI^{-1}$ in (1) and we get that the upper part where the lightning hits is about $2.5~m$ wide. Hence we conclude that **visually** the lightning bolt, which hit CN Tower and was taken in the given picture, must be at least $2.5m$ wide or greater (lower bound).

Comment: It's hard to tell how much of that is actual lighting bolt width and how much is a very bright light source being spread out by aberration in the camera lens then saturating a bunch of pixels.

Comment: Well, it's just a crude estimate here, you have to start from somewhere, especially when OP has asked "visual width" of the lightning bolt, not for actual dimensions. So it depends what "visual width" is for OP, it can be that saturation of pixels goes into that definition as well. Besides human eye also has same saturation effect on light receptors, but if we omit this factor (and maybe others), then not much "visual" things are left.

Comment: Does the human eye have the same effects as a CMOS or CCD camera sensor where heavily over-saturating one pixel will lead to charge leaking out into the buckets for neighbouring pixels?  That "bloom" effect @AXensen pointed out is well known.  In a CMOS sensor, with the amount of stray charge leaking out can even affect the circuits that are suppose to measure the value, affecting the reference voltage, leading to the "black sun" effect.  See [What is that black thing in center of every star in this JWST image?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/59680) for some discussion of that effect.

Comment: I'm not saying that eye photoreceptor cell has exactly same saturation effect as CMOS or CCD sensor. Of course not, because light capturing mechanisms differ and eye has additional guard system for avoiding saturation. But it will not help in case of very high flash intensities, you can read an article about [cone cell saturation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0042698978900263). IMHO, end result of any optical system reaching saturation is the same,- it will not register the shape of source, but give just a white (or black in case of heavily over-exposed CMOS) spot.

Comment: @PeterCordes Probably not the eye itself, but the processing that goes on in the optic nerve and visual cortex is likely to "spread out" a very bright signal.

Comment: @Spencer from the given link _Cone saturation refers to the fact that an intensity (the saturating intensity) of a flash can be found such that the cone system cannot detect increments upon this flash no matter how intense these increments are made_ So cone receptors tries to scale response to bigger photon stream, but once it reaches maximum step,- can't adjust no more and saturation happens.

Comment: The image is of some finite exposure time - the shutter wasn't opened for just some fraction of the flash so any motion of the bolt would exposure adjacient pixels and lead to an over estimate of the bolt diameter

Comment: @DDuck Yes, but the human eye does not have an analogue to a camera shutter, so visual signal must be averaged in brains. Hence it's not clear what camera exposure times would better represent human visual system. (Again keep in mind, that OP has asked for the size of bolt appearing to the naked eye, so any inconsistencies or imperfections of eye must be replicated with camera capture process.)

Comment: @Peter_Cordes the natural lens of an eye scatters light more than glass does. A very bright flash will overload adjacent cones with small-angle scattered light. The older the eye the worse this gets (pre-cataract, and eventually full cataract).

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether the results of this kind of analysis yield consistent results over different pictures of lightning.

Comment: +1 While this answer doesn't have much scientific value, it does seem to match the nature of the question.

Answer (score 26):

There are a couple ways the answer could go.

The 1 inch diameter probably refers to plasma generated by the bolt. The air for some distance around it might be hot enough to glow.

Then there are visual effects. You can't see anything smaller than a receptor in your eye. This means anything smaller than about an arc minute appears to be an arc minute. You can see this in starlight. The actual angle of the disk is too small to resolve with a good telescope. You just see the minimum size your eye can resolve.

Your eyesight might not be perfect. A blurry image appear bigger. You might move your eyes during the stroke. This would make the bolt cover more receptors.

Photographs of lightning would be subject to the same considerations.

Comment: Alright. In that case, let’s go with the first way the answer could go. Next, we use a photograph of Lightning for an example. The brightest parts of the bolt is what we’re looking for the diameter of. Any part that could be said as being part of the bolt but has a distinguishable color to it would not be included in our calculation.

Comment: @GodzillaLouise - the problem with how big it appears visually is that it cannot necessarily be translated to a diameter in a consistent way; e.g, if you go by that method, a lighting bolt at some distance may give you a larger diameter than a nearby one. And the apparent size can vary during the same footage - see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-LPERlRHYA

Comment: Also, add scattering of light by the natural lens of an eye. It's not as clear as glass even for a young person, and by the time we reach 65 many of us have pre-cataracts (noticeable cloudiness, and increased dazzle by bright lights).

Comment: To put some concrete numbers to it, if "... anything smaller than about an arc minute appears to be an arc minute,"  then visually, a lightning bolt is indistinguishable from a cylinder that is 0.0003 times the distance to your eye.  If it's 1km away from you, it will look to be 0.3m wide.  If it's 10km away, it will look 3m wide.  100km away bolts will look 30m wide.  (rough numbers, of course)

Answer (score 15):

When I was a teenager I had a newspaper delivery round; one morning a storm broke as I was out delivering papers and a lightning bolt struck the ground just in front of me. It seemed to me to be about a 1 to 1.5 metres in diameter. The blast (there's not really any other word for it) was enough to throw me backwards off my bicycle. About 30 seconds later another bolt struck the ground across the road; it also seemed to be just as wide as the first.

Comment: Did you get a shock? That could have made your muscles contract, and that could have thrown you off.

Comment: That must have been very bright. Did you have two separate after images?

Comment: @mmesser314, "shocked" or not depends on where the victim's feet are planted relative to the voltage gradient on the ground. One could get lucky (probably facing directly toward the center of the strike) and both feet experience exactly the same voltage. Or, one could get unlucky, (probably with one's right or left shoulder facing) and have a potential difference of thousands of volts between your two feet. It tends to be more deadly if you have four feet, and you're standing head toward the tree, seeking shelter from the rain. https://wcti12.com/archive/farmer-cows-struck-killed-by-lightning

Comment: @SolomonSlow - The bicycle frame may have helped reduce field gradients near him.

Comment: D'oh! "Off my bicycle"...means...they must have  been _on_ a bicycle. I see that now. 

Comment: @mmesser314, so shall we recommend riding bicycles for lightning protection?

Comment: At about age 16 I saw a lighting bolt hit a tree about 5m away, a friend had just kicked a ball in that direction so it happened that about 5 of us were looking directly at it. My memory of it would suggest it was about 300mm in diameter, but this was so long ago ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I love how each answer is 'well you can't really answer that' or "let's try to do math from these pictures' and wocky just says "when I was struck by lightning it looked about this big."

Comment: @akostadinov - I don't recommend bicycling where lightning is about to strike. If lightning does strike near you, I recommend being lucky enough not to be electrocuted.

Comment: Rubber or plastic shoe soles are good insulators. People with such shoes fare a lot better than cows do, should lightning strike very near them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several contributing effects:

1. The actual initial width of the plasma itself. This is surprisingly small - [this](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1029/2019JD030693) paper indicates that peak optical output occurs at only ~3mm radius for the modeled 20kA stroke.
2. The plasma expansion with time. As the return stroke starts, you get a column of very hot plasma in the air. This is obviously unstable, and rapidly radially expands. The plasma also rapidly cools... but doesn't do so instantly. Said paper indicates that even 50us into the return stroke there is still a fair amount of optical output, and the plasma has expanded significantly (to ~7mm radius). Unfortunately, figure 6d) stops at 50us.
3. Diffraction limit. The human eye is [~3x](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195578/is-the-human-eye-diffraction-limited-or-is-there-another-limiting-factor) worse than the theoretical maximum here, at somewhere around 60 arcseconds. This in turn works out to somewhere around 30cm at 1km.
4. Dazzle and other effects. Lightning is bright <sup>[Citation Needed]</sup>. Our eyes are not perfect, and internal optical reflections happen. This is somewhat comparing apples to oranges here, but [some empirical equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326475069_Determination_of_a_laser_eye_dazzle_safety_framework/link/5b59d7270f7e9bc79a666ec6/download) from laser dazzle are as follows. (These equations assume monochromatic light; lightning's optical spectrum [isn't](http://www.atmo.arizona.edu/students/courselinks/spring13/atmo589/ATMO489_online/lecture_26/lect18a_spectroscopy_thunder.html). Ditto, lightning is not a coherent source, and is a line rather than a point. Ditto, these equations are more designed for steady-state, whereas lightning isn't.) Said 20kA stroke has a peak optical power on the order of 4.3MW/m. Take a slice of this 3m long (diffraction-limited at 10km), and that's a peak optical output of ~10mW/m^2. Peak optical output seems to be in the blue region of the spectrum, so $V = 0.0647$ from their paper. Multiplying through, that's a MDE of ~660uW/cm^2. From the paper's table, this indicates this would be between 1-5 degrees radius of dazzle in full daylight, or >20 degrees of dazzle at dusk/dawn (the paper indicates 20 degrees of dazzle at ~450uW/cm^2). Note that even 1 degree radius of dazzle at 10km is an effective visible width of ~350 meters.

Again, note bunches of caveats.